# The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context Dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I'm trying to configure the nlogging in my dotnet core application.while creating the method CreateHostBuilder I'm facing a compiling error "The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context". I had provided the namespaces too.
My program.cs file code is as follows :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               })
               .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
               {
                   logging.ClearProviders();
                   logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
               })
               .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
```

Getting the exception at "Host".

Comment: Check your version mate, are you using 2.x or 3.0. Net Core 2.x Doesn't support `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` its for 3.0

Comment: @keysl Got it. can we do the thing in 2.1 ?

Comment: For 2.1 you need to use the `WebHost` instead of `Host`

Comment: @keysl , When I use webhost. I'm facing the issue with "ConfigureWebHostDefaults"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Net 3.0 Syntax at Net Core 2.x Project
`Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults` are [3.0 specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.generichostbuilderextensions.configurewebhostdefaults?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

You have 2 options here

1. Upgrade the project to 3.0
2. Convert your Configuration to 2.x specific  to something along like this

like this

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                   logging.ClearProviders();
                   logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
               })
       .UseNLog(); // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
```

Comment: See also NLog guide for asp.net core 2: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2